# Is there a way to encase a text which contains lots of operators/formatting and ignore all interpretation?

Tags: python, string

So for example:

```
txt = r"<img alt="image tags" height="652" id="image" onclick="Note.toggle();" src="https://us.example.com//images/1/5d2.gif?1" width="600"/>"
```

Now, clearly, this doesn't work for a lot of reasons, namely quotations and escape characters.  It's possible to manually format each txt but this is intended to automatically find img from webpages.

I think Regex might be a clear solution here but if there is just some character to place before and after then that would be ideal.  I'm a lot more used to C++ where this would have been trivial, I apologize for my lack of experience.

Comment: Use single quotes to encase your string, your text contains double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using [triple quotes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/triple-quotes-in-python/) will solve the problem you are facing:

```py
txt = r"""<img alt="image tags" height="652" id="image" onclick="Note.toggle();" src="https://us.example.com//images/1/5d2.gif?1" width="600"/>"""
```

Triple quotes allow you to have strings spanning multiple lines and also avoid difficulties in using single or double quotes in the string.  The `r` prefix escapes any special characters (e.g., backslash) in the string.

Comment: This is it, I'll accept answer in 7 minutes.  Again, I apologize for my inexperience.

Comment: @JonesCrimson No need to apologize; I was in the same place as you at some point

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are searching for is `r"""..."""`

```
txt = r"""<img alt="image tags" height="652" id="image" onclick="Note.toggle();" src="https://us.example.com//images/1/5d2.gif?1" width="600"/>"""
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could simply use single quotation marks.

```
txt = r'<img alt="image tags" height="652" id="image" onclick="Note.toggle();" src="https://us.example.com//images/1/5d2.gif?1" width="600"/>'
```